# dispatching 'userLogoutAction' when JWT has expired throws an error in 'Menu.js'

Tags: react-admin

In order to do an automatic log-off (triggered by the react app, no user interaction and no API calls) from my react-admin app (react-admin version 2.8.3) as soon as the JWT expires. I do a periodic check and dispatch the `userLogout` action which I imported from `ra-core/authActions` the same way the Logout button (`ra-ui-materialui/auth/Logout`) does.

Unfortunately `ra-ui-materialui/esm/layout/Menu.js` throws an error at line 116 complaining about an undefined property: ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of null***

```
return {
  114 |     open: state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen,
  115 |     resources: getResources(state),
> 116 |     pathname: state.router.location.pathname
  117 |   };
```

Using the Chrome redux tools I can see that the redux-store `router` has a property `location` that is null.

Is there a better way to log out the user after the JWT has expired? If not, what do I need to do to make the `userLogout` action work?

Maybe someone can explain why the `Menu.js` seems to be tightly coupled to the `userLogout` action.

The source code of my component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { userLogout } from 'react-admin'
import { hasValidJWT } from '../authProvider'

class PeriodicAuthCheck extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // interval in seconds
        this.interval = 60
    }

    authCheck(loginPath, dispatchAction) {
        if (!hasValidJWT()) {
            if (window.location.hash !== `#${loginPath}`) {
                console.log(`JWT has expired, redirecting to ${loginPath}`)
                /*
                  this is my workaround:
                  window.location.replace(`/#${loginPath}`)
                */
                dispatchAction(loginPath)
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.authCheck(this.props.loginPath, this.props.logout)
        this.interval = setInterval(this.authCheck, this.interval * 1000, this.props.loginPath, this.props.logout)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.interval) {
            clearInterval(this.interval)
            this.interval = undefined
        }
    }

    render() {
        return null
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logout: (loginPath) => dispatch(userLogout(loginPath))
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PeriodicAuthCheck)
```

Thank you in advance!
Thomas

Comment: what does the actual dispatch of the action look like?

Comment: @Kosch I've added the source code of the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the httpClient for your dataProvider.
For me it worked only if I removed the token explicitly and forwarded the browser to the login form.

```
if (401 === responseStatusCode) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    window.location = '/#/login';
}
```

It isn't the nicest solution imo but it get's the job done.
Would love to see other solutions to this problem as well.

Comment: I was not specific about my intent so I'v edited my post. I want to to an auto log-off so I check the JWT periodically on the client without any API calls.

Comment: I see, indeed I misinterpreted that.
I take it you are using `redirectTo` parameter for the `userLogout` action creator, where are you redirecting to?

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. I've added the source code of the component. When the JWT expires the user gets redirected to the '/login' path.